# How to prevent ghost image when dragging element, but still use drag events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating custom drag functionality. I want to be able to drag an element, but I am using translation to actually move the element while dragging. It works well, but when dragged, the ghost image still appears, making it look kind of blurred while dragging.

I am using `element.addEventListener("dragover", ()=>{})`. As well as `dragstart` and `dragend`.

Is their a way to prevent the ghost image of the element while still retaining drag functionality?

```
<body>
    <style>
        .dragContainer{
            height: 200px;
            width: 500px;
            background: red;
        }

        .draggable{
            display: flex;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="dragContainer">
        <a class="draggable" href=""></a>
    </div>

    <script>
        let initialOffset = 0;
        document.querySelector(".dragContainer").addEventListener("dragover", (event)=>{
            let offset = event.clientX - initialOffset;
            document.querySelector(".draggable").style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
        });

        document.querySelector(".dragContainer").addEventListener("dragstart", (event)=>{
            initialOffset = event.clientX;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This example shows very generally what I am trying to do. In Firefox, when you click/drag, it creates a "ghost image" that follows the mouse while dragging. In Chrome it will just create a small bit of text as a "ghost image" which also follows the mouse.

I want to get rid of those.

Comment: Could you put a runnable snippet into your question so we can see the shadowing, and check that proposed solutions will work? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In the dragstart eventlistener, set effectAllowed property to none.

Comment: Tried this, it had no effect.

Comment: Modify the dragstart event listener to call preventDefault() on the event object. Call preventDefault() mentod on the dragstart event. Also add draggable="true" to the a element like <a class="draggable" href="" draggable="true"></a> because is necessary to enable drag and drop.Here is how you can do it  document.querySelector(".draggable").addEventListener("dragstart", (event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            initialOffset = event.clientX;

Comment: Links and text don't require draggable="true", they are draggable by default. event.preventDefault() makes the entire thing un-draggable. Using that does prevent the ghost image, but it also prevents dragging altogether. The "dragover" event will not fire at all.